# How do I use smart.json to tell meteorite to use a stable version of meteor?

Tags: meteor

As far as I can tell, the point of meteorite is to simplify dealing with which versions of plugins and branch of meteor your project needs. But I don't want to follow the churn on a branch of meteor; I want to use a stable version. It seems as if this should be possible. How do I do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can [specify alternate branches and forks](https://github.com/oortcloud/meteorite) respectively:

```
{
  meteor: {
    "branch": "devel",
    "git": "https://github.com/meteor/meteor.git"
  }
}
```

Per the documentation:

> The meteor specification is not required. Meteor's public repo checked out to the master branch is the default. You can specify meteor.branch and meteor.git to use alternate branches and forks respectively.

To use a stable version, simply omit the `meteor` section from the smart.json file altogether and you'll use the most recent, stable version.

Comment: Thanks for answering. But what if I want to be able to take my project and in 6 months on a different machine get the same version of Meteor? "The most recent, stable version" doesn't cut it then. I need somewhere to put a version number. I know there are version tags in git; is there any way to put a tag instead of a branch in Meteorite?

Comment: Hmm... I guess I could fork meteor, and link to the fork. Seems like overkill, though; isn't there a better way?

Comment: That would be a way to ensure you've got a static version. I just created [this issue](https://github.com/oortcloud/meteorite/issues/74) on github. Perhaps this will be available in the future.

Comment: You should add brackets on branch and git. Otherwise it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 7):

Use tag to choose a particular Meteor version:

```
"meteor": {
  "git": "https://github.com/meteor/meteor.git",
  "tag": "release/0.6.3.1"
},
```

(See --tag in http://oortcloud.github.com/meteorite/)

Comment: Neither the `release/0.7.2` or `v0.7.2` seem to work anymore as of today. Do you know the right syntax as of now?

Comment: Meteorite no longer controls the Meteor version.  Instead, use the "meteor update" command (http://docs.meteor.com/#meteorupdate)

Comment: Was trying to get some Travis CI tests to work on branches that weren't updated to 0.8 yet. Oh well...

Comment: Hm, but this is a problem because packages do not have meteor version linked to them. smart.json was the only way to require a package to be tested under a particular Meteor version.